# TP-Link Archer T2UH

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, wifi

I have recently bought a TP-Link Archer T2UH AC600 WiFi dongle for my Raspberry-Pi 2B, and it's not working. I have tried to install its driver (mt7610) and make it work, also following various posts in this forum but, this resulted in no success. Also, the Pi freezes frequently when connecting the dongle to it. Can anyone help, please?

Update:

- The dongle can see SSIDs but not connect to them!
- iwlist shows all the AP's available with their respective signal strengths and quality.
- iwconfig shows only the frequency, but not the SSID and other information, they are marked as ""

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not put meta information like "[Solved]" in the title. That's not how things are handled here. Accept a valid and helpful answer instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following are the steps to make TP-Link Archer T2UH AC600 to work with Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. The following steps can also be found on the Raspberry Pi forum, where I originally gave the answer.

1. Install the driver provided by @MrEngman by entering the following commands in terminal:

   `wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/install-wifi.tar.gz
   tar xzf install-wifi.tar.gz
   sudo ./install-wifi`
2. Go to /etc/network/interfaces, open and add the following:

   `wpa-driver wext`
3. Reboot, turn on WiFi and select SSID
4. Enter password (if required)
5. Enjoy :)

Comment: This answer is no longer viable as the linked driver package no longer exists. Is there a suitable mirror of the file, or better yet a home page of some kind that updates could be tracked from?

Comment: Very sorry to hear! Have you tried searching for other drivers, as there is no other mirrors? It's driver is the MT7610. Also, the script I had which downloads the required driver on its own is not working either.

Comment: The compiled drivers seem to be here: http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/mt7610-drivers/ and the auto-install script here http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/install-wifi ...The answer referred to at the Raspberry Pi forums (and where these new links are) is this one: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=896270

Answer (score 0):

Newer drivers are at https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au and if you read the [readme](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/blob/v5.6.4.2/README.md#for-raspberry-rpi), you'll find what you're looking for.

### 32 bit kernel

For 32 bit ARM CPU + kernels (e.g. running `uname -m` gives `armv7l`) it is:

```
sudo apt install git dkms raspberrypi-kernel-headers
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = y/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n/g' Makefile
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = n/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y/g' Makefile
sudo make dkms_install
```

### 64 bit kernel

For other readers that might be using a 64 bit kernel (e.g. Raspberry Pi 4), the second last line is different, so the instructions become:

```
sudo apt install git dkms raspberrypi-kernel-headers
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = y/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n/g' Makefile
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = n/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y/g' Makefile
sudo make dkms_install
```